# Album/user for deep link http://i.imgur.com/JNwPo.png

Tags: imgur

How do I find the album and user for the Imgur deeplinked image 
"https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSACF.png", and for Imgur deeplinked images in general?

I tried googling "link:https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSACF.png" (without quotes) to no avail.

Is there an Imgur-specific way to do this and/or is this intentional: 
Imgur doesn't want to map deeplinked images to users/albums? (although 
a brute force algorithm on each image/user would still work)

Answer (score 3):

Delete the `i.`  and the `.png` in the URL.

For example:

"https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSACF.png"

becomes:

"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkz0K.jpg"

Comment: Thanks. This puts the image on a page, but the "next post" just appears to be the most current viral images, and not an actual album?

Comment: Hmm.   I see what you mean.  At the moment I don't have an answer but if I find a way I'll inform you first.